# MEGA ADK fails to work with jellybean

Tags: android

I have an arduino Mega ADK board which I have been using with my Samsung Galaxy nexus. The board has worked just fine as a usb accessory but after the jellybean update, the board failed to connect with a `could not read device protocol version`. Is there something that I am missing or is this a bug that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Google changed Android Open Accessory protocol version in API level 16 ( >= 4.1).  AOA in the new version (v2) is not backward compatible. I'm getting the same error on my MEGA ADK you got. Read somewhere that there is a newer version of Arduino ADK library that works with the new AOA and all you have to do is recompile your Arduino code.

Try out the lates adk version
http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk.html

I'm still trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Also it should be libraries from adk_release_20120606.zip uploaded with IDE Arduino 1.00 or higher